# In UWP(C#), is there a way to call other windows?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to use DLL like User32.dll in UWP in order to pass on events like mouse click to other UWP/WPF apps.

From my research, UWP is a sandbox and it isn't allowed to do so. But There are ways like AppServiceConnection, but this method needs to be declared in the Visual Studio Project and it gets pretty messy when tried.

Is there a way to implement Win32 Dlls to UWP so that I can get other window program(HWND) and manipulate it?

Comment: Are you talking about your own Win32 app or just any Win32 app in general?  If it's the latter, then no, there's no way. UWP apps don't have access to the OS processes. If it's your Win32 app you can run it as a full-trust integrated app. You can also communicate with it using a network protocol like WebSocket. I think App Services is just for UWP to UWP communication.